# Not sure how to approch this, doing some math with error checking and updating my new value in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
        if (freightCostTotal == 0)
        {
            freightCount = 1;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[iFreightCount].Value = "1";
            if (freightCostDefinedTotal != 0)
            {
                freightCostTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(pcsg.Freight_CountColumn.Table.Rows[0]["Fixed Freight"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[iCost_Prior_ReCompute].Value.ToString()))
                    Cost_Prior_ReCompute = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[iCost_Prior_ReCompute].Value.ToString());

                //freightCostPercentTotal = 0.05M;
                //decimal costFreight = Convert.ToDecimal(pcsg.Freight_CountColumn.Table.Rows[0]["Cost"].ToString());
                freightCostTotal = (Cost_Prior_ReCompute * freight_perc_);
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[iFreight].Value = String.Format("{0:0.00}", freightCostTotal);
        }
```

The following is  not working.  This is my first attempt at doing sql math

```
select freightCostTotal, Cost_Prior_ReCompute],freight_perc_, FixedFreight,
            if (freightCostTotal == 0) then freightCount = 1;
                if (freightCostDefinedTotal != 0) then freightCostDefinedTotal = FixedFreight else
                 set  freightCostTotal = (Cost_Prior_ReCompute * freight_perc_);
from VF_CasINV_Cost
```

Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"?  Is it throwing errors or just not selecting what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're after exactly, but here's a start below. FYI -- your conditional on Cost_Prior_Recompute needs a default / else value -- I just put a '?' in there for now, since I can't tell what it should be.

Also -- I can't tell if freigntCostTotal is an actually field in your database that you're trying to update, or if you plan to just compute it based on other fields each time.  So far, I'm assuming you're just going to compute it.

So this is how you would select -- keeping in mind (I assume from reading your code) you are looking for data where the frieghtCostTotal has NOT been updated in the database yet.

```
SELECT
   1 as freightCount,
   CASE WHEN freightCostDefinedTotal <> 0
      THEN FixedFreight
      ELSE ISNULL(Cost_Prior_ReCompute,?) * freight_perc_
      END as freigntCostTotal,
   Cost_Prior_ReCompute,
   freight_perc_,
   FixedFreight
FROM
   VF_CasINV_Cost
WHERE
   freightCostTotal = 0
```

Alternatively, you could just pull the data out like this, but it will get all data, not just the freightCostTotal = 0 data.

```
SELECT
   1 as freightCount,
   freigntCostTotal,
   Cost_Prior_ReCompute,
   freight_perc_,
   FixedFreight
FROM
   VF_CasINV_Cost
```

Here's how you would update.  BTW -- If you're new to updating with SQL, I'd highly recommend you test this out on some non-production data first.  Or at least, back-up your table first.

```
UPDATE VF_CasINV_Cost
SET freightCostTotal = CASE WHEN freightCostDefinedTotal <> 0
                          THEN FixedFreight
                          ELSE ISNULL(Cost_Prior_ReCompute,?) * freight_perc_
                          END
WHERE freightCostTotal = 0
```

Comment: Yes, I need to save freightCostTotal and I get the following error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '?'.

Comment: You need to replace the ? with a number.  I just put the ? in there because I didn't know what number you wanted to use as your default value.  In otherwords, ISNULL() is saying "If Cost_Prior_Recompute is null, then use this number instead: ___".  I'll  update the answer to show you how to update the database as well.

Comment: I have been working on this and this what I have come up with

Comment: SELECT 
   CASE 
        WHEN @freightCostTotal = 0 THEN ([Cost Prior ReCompute] * (@freight_perc_ / 100))
        WHEN @nc = 0 THEN LeastOfThree - (@freightCostTotal / [Freight Count])
        WHEN [Freight Count] = 0 THEN 1  
  END as freigntCostTotal, 
    @nc,
   [Freight Count], 
   [Cost Prior ReCompute],
   @freight_perc_,
   @FixedFreight,
 NewCost, 
    LeastOfThree
FROM VF_CasINV_Cost
.

Comment: with results:2.200000 NULL 0 44.00 5 10 0.00 44.00,  the first null is nc.  how do I get it to calculate nc and replace [Freight Count] with 1 when = 0, then to update nc in the table for 5000 rows?

Comment: Evaluate Frieght Count like this:  CASE [Freight Count] WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE [Freight Count] END